# Azure function to convert csv to excel file

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have requirement to read data from azure sql server and write in excel blob using data factory. i created csv file from azure sql server using datafactory copy activity. i have no idea how to convert csv to excel or directly read excel from azure sql using data factory. I searched on internet and found azure functions as an option.

Any suggestions you all have about saving CSV to XLSX via Azure Functions?

Comment: The quickest way that comes to my mind is to use a python function where yuo import pandas and read the csv then rewriting it as excel. Reference for the code here https://datatofish.com/csv-to-excel-python/. You have to download the file from Azure first, and then upload it back after the conversion, doc here https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

Answer (score 1):

> Excel format is supported for the following connectors: Amazon S3,
> Azure Blob, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1, Azure Data Lake Storage
> Gen2, Azure File Storage, File System, FTP, Google Cloud Storage,
> HDFS, HTTP, and SFTP. It is supported as source but not sink.

As the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel) says, Excel format is not supported as sink by now. So you can't directly convert csv file to excel file using Copy activity.

In Azure function, you can create a python function and use pandas to read csv file. Then convert it to excel file as @Marco Massetti comments.